# jQuery UI Autocomplete not firing select event in IE8 with mouse click

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The problem that I have only appears on IE8. While debugging I found that if I select an option from the autocomplete with the arrow and enter keys, the select event is fired, and then the blur. When I select an option with a mouse click, only the blur event happens. Result is that the textbox is not updated and the dropdown list is still hovering there in a semi-transparent state.

I have done a lot of search on the issue, with and without adding IE8 to my search. I found a lot of similar problems being reported, but none of the cases/solutions helped to fix the missing select event call. I have also tried by adding a handler to "autocompleteselect" but this event is still not fired.

```
    cityName.autocomplete({
        source: getCities,
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 100,
        html: true,
        select:function(event, ui) {
            $('#citycode').val(ui.item.citycode);
        }
    });

    cityName.blur(function() {
        cityName.autocomplete('disable');
        otherMethodCall();
    });
```

Using these versions:
jQuery: 1.9.1
jQuery UI: 1.10.2